# "mount -t TYPE /" - how to know that what could the "TYPE" be?

Tags: linux, filesystems

OS: ex.: Ubuntu 10.04 - how to know that what does the "mount -t TYPE" knows? I mean is there a command to list the supported filesystem types using with mount??

UPDATE: is the following cmd always good?:

```
cat /proc/filesystems | awk '{print $NF}' | sed '/^$/d'
sysfs
rootfs
bdev
proc
cgroup
cpuset
tmpfs
devtmpfs
debugfs
securityfs
sockfs
pipefs
anon_inodefs
inotifyfs
devpts
ext3
ext2
ext4
ramfs
hugetlbfs
ecryptfs
fuse
fuseblk
fusectl
mqueue
binfmt_misc
iso9660
vfat
udf
reiserfs
xfs
jfs
msdos
ntfs
minix
hfs
hfsplus
qnx4
ufs
btrfs
```

Comment: You cant just choose any arbitrary type for the filesystem youre mounting. If your filesystem is EXT4, then the type has to be EXT4. However in most cases you dont even need to specify the type, it is determined automatically.

Comment: yes that command works fine

Comment: No, that command not works fine. If the first column is empty it removes the entire line. `awk '{print $NF}' /proc/filesystems` would work better.

Comment: updated with the $NF part, nice catch :)

Comment: are you looking for what filesystem type a drive you currently have installed has? if so type blkid as root

Comment: I'm looking for a list that the "mount -t TYPE" supports! all of them. So all of the thing I can put in the "TYPE"

Comment: Dear fellow Googlers: If you're here because you can't get a mystery image to mount, there's a chance your image may be a _full disk_ rather than a partition. Try `fdisk -l /your/file.img`; if this yields meaningful results, check out [this blog post](https://dustymabe.com/2012/12/15/mounting-a-partition-within-a-disk-image/) for some guidance with `losetup` and `partx`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This should work for ubuntu as well as Debian, type the following:

```
cat /proc/filesystems
```

This will output what your current kernel supports

ah now i understand your question better, type:

```
 man mount
```

and scroll down to -t and there will be a list of supported filesystems that mount it self supports, but this is dependent on what your kernal supports

Comment: but now always, see: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/tell-what-filesystems-linux-kernel-can-handle.html comment part about NFS

Comment: this is not a 100% answer, I could google for this too :P

Comment: If a post would only count as an answer if it was *not to be found somewhere* with a search engine, this site would be a lot smaller...

Comment: I wanted to mean that I alredy knowed that answer, I post it in the question too, before this answer:P

Comment: lol my page had not update until i posted it then i saw your answer

Answer (score 3):

I am running arch linux and the suggested solution `cat /proc/filesystems | awk '{print $NF}' | sed '/^$/d'` did not provide me a complete list of filesystems that my kernel currently supports/has the modules to support. After digging around it looks like /proc/filesystems just lists the filesystems that already have their kernel modules loaded (or don't need modules like sysfs?).

Based on yakamok's suggestion to read the man page I found that the documentation about the -t parmater has another command `cat /proc/filesystems | awk '{print $NF}' | sed '/^$/d'` that shows  additional filesystem kernel modules that are available but not currently loaded.

Putting it all together I now have this command that I believe when run will give you a complete list of all filesystems that your current linux system supports:

`(cat /proc/filesystems | awk '{print $NF}' | sed '/^$/d'; ls -1 /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/fs) | sort -u`

This is basically both commands output listed one after another all piped to sort with the -u (unique) option turned on to filter out duplicates.

Answer (score -3):

easy way to find partitions, drives, and filesystems

```
lsblk -f
```